# Why doesn't join() work on strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

In Javascript, strings are arrays. `join("glue")` joins arrays with the glue. So why doesn't this work?

```
"abcdefg".join("-");
```

Expected output: `a-b-c-d-e-f-g`

Actual output: `Uncaught TypeError: string.join is not a function`

Comment: Because the `.join` method is defined for arrays, but not for strings?

Comment: Your premise is false. Strings are objects, like everything else, but they are not arrays.

Comment: (In certain *other* languages Strings are sequences-of-characters and thus 'inherit' the common behaviors of such sequences; as pointed out, this is *not* the case in JavaScript even though Strings and Arrays share the ["duck-typeable"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) `length` and `[]` get-indexer.)

Comment: In javascript, strings are not arrays. In C, strings are arrays but not all languages agree with C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by other answers, strings are not arrays. However it *is* possible to use array methods on strings using `call`.

```
"abcdefg".join("-"); // fails with typeerror
```

But you can get it to work this way:

```
Array.prototype.join.call("abcdefg", "-"); // works
```

Using `call` in this way will successfully run `join()` on the string literal `"abcdefg"` with `-` as glue.

Answer (score 3):

Strings **are not** arrays, certainly they behave like those, but they are not arrays.

In order to get working your snippet you need to "split" your string into an array of chunks.

Maybe this snippet would do the trick.

```
"abcdef".split('').join('-');
```

Notice how I inserted between the `.join` call and the object (in this case the static string `"abcdef"`) the `.split` method call (also notice its argument which means use every character).

Using `.split` converts an string INTO a pure array, and then you can use the `.join` method.

Check out MDN Docs:

- [`<Array>.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [`<String>.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Yes, I did end up using `split()` to get it to work, but I just wanted to know why it was necessary. I guess the tautological fact that strings are not arrays is a decent reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
"abcdefg".split('').join('-');
```

Answer (score 0):

convert string to character array before join.

```
"abcdefg".split("").join("-")
```